# How to access button_click event in parent form from an inherited form in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

In my windows form application, I have a main form with toolstrip menu items and buttons that trigger specific inherited forms and open them in the dock window. On the main form, the categoriesToolStripMenuItem open the categories form which is an inherited form where user can perform CRUD operation on the data.

Another inherited form is the products form where user have to choose a specific category from the combobox and add products to that category or edit and delete an existing product from that specific category. To keep the application up and running, I want the user not to be able to open the products form if there is no category added yet. Instead, I want him to add a category before adding products to it.

As soon he click on the button that open product's form, I wan't the click event of categoriesToolStripMenuItem to be triggered if no categories are present in the database. Following is the categoriesToolStripMenuItem click event.

```
public void categoriesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fCategories == null)
        {
            fCategories = new frmCategories();
            fCategories.Show(dp, WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockState.Document);
        }
        else
        {
            fCategories.Activate();
        }
    }
```

On my `Product_Load` event, I want to trigger the `categoriesToolStripMenuItem` on the top like this but it is not triggering like I need it to be:

```
private void frmProducts_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillGrid();


        DataTable dt = DataAccess.Select("select categoryname from categories order by categoryname");
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
frmMain mainForm = new frmMain();
            categoriesToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender, e);
            return;
        }
}
```

Is there any way to access this event?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the Load event will only happen the first time the form is loaded (in other words when it is first created). If you are hiding it and showing it your Load handler will not be called. You would probably be better off handling the VisibleChanged event to trigger categories.

Also, calling the Click handler directly is not wrong, but you could also call categoriesToolStripMenuItem.PerformClick() if you have access to the button itself. Then you don't need to worry about sending a sender nor eventArgs and all subscribers to the Click will get called.